# How can i fix the auto suggestion for buildFeatures

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a problem with my android studio project when I migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding.

I put this code manually (because when I type `buildFea` it didn't show any auto-suggestion)

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
```

The library `buildFeatures` is sync well.

The problem is when I input `ActivityMainBinding` class it doesn't recognize my package.

I'm a beginner anyway, please help me solve this problem and if you can please give me a detailed explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: Which Android Gradle Plugin version are you using? If it's older than 4.0 then instead of `buildFeatures { viewBinding true }` you should use `viewBinding { enabled = true }`. And if it's older than 3.6 then there's no support for viewbinding.

Comment: I already use version 4.1.2 but it still not working even when I use viewBinding { enabled = true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. If someone get an error like what I got, you can try to rebuild your project on `Build > Rebuild Projects` and the `ActivityMainBinding` class will no longer unrecognize your package.